# How to implement magento's store select field?

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

## Synopsis

I am implementing a small module that stores a single record in my own table, this record **must** relate to a store; so I decided to adopt the store visibility field from the `Catalog > Products` section (which is the same as Cms > Pages).

The snippet below will give me an array of store ids.  I want this field to be a singleton (i.e. only a single store to be selected)

```
// Check is single store mode
if (! Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $field = $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'select', [
        'name'      => 'stores[]',
        'label'     => $this->__('Store View'),
        'title'     => $this->__('Store View'),
        'required'  => true,
        'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
        'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
    ]);
    $field->setRenderer($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element'));
} else {
    $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', [
        'name'      => 'stores[]',
        'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
    ]);
    $model->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
}
```

Comment: The code snippet appears to be from the cms grid where the store options are not multiple select. I am a bit confused as what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidManners the Cms pages and Catalog Products *Store  Visibility* I believe are one of the same. Currently you can hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click to select multiple stores (I want it so you can't do this).

Comment: is this for the an edit page or a grid page?

Comment: @DavidManners - I have updated the question, I hope this is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet you are provided is from the file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Block/Grid.php`. This code comes inside a protected method `_prepareColumns()` and which is used to define each columns that appears in `CMS ->Pages` grid page. This column is actually renders a dropdown section in the grid page.

You may porbably referencing to Edit page of CMS page. The Block file correspond to the CMS edit page is  `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Block/Edit/Form.php`. The action method that we need to concentrate is `_prepareForm()`. There you can see the multiple selection definition of store views.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Check is single store mode
     */
    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $field =$fieldset->addField('store_id', 'multiselect', array(
            'name'      => 'stores[]',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
        ));
        $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element');
        $field->setRenderer($renderer);
    }
    else {
        $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name'      => 'stores[]',
            'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
        ));
        $model->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
    }
```

From above code you can see that, the store view field is of type `multiselect`. You need to use this code snippet in order to achieve you goal.

### EDIT

In order to use it as  a dropdown, you probably need to change `multiselect` to `select`. Then use it in your module.
Hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: This code has made me realise I was looking in the entirely wrong place.  The solution is that i needed to change multiselect to select - also this was inside my form block not my grid block (derp), Thanks

Comment: @Ash : so your problem solved ? Glad to help you

Comment: yeah i'll accept this as solution.